# pyspark conditional cumulative sum

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe with two dates - bill and payment date. I want to create a column that has the sum of amounts of bills billed and paid before the bill date of that row. Also, this needs to be done for every buyer ID individually. Example:

| Buyer | Bill date | Payment Date | Amount | New Column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-02-02 | 2021-02-20 | 100 | 0 |
| 1 | 2021-03-02 | 2021-03-10 | 400 | 100 |
| 1 | 2021-04-02 | 2021-05-25 | 500 | 500 |
| 1 | 2021-05-02 | 2021-06-03 | 300 | 500 |
| 1 | 2021-06-02 | 2021-07-20 | 200 | 1000 |
| 2 | 2021-04-10 | 2021-05-25 | 1000 | 0 |
| 2 | 2021-05-11 | 2021-06-03 | 3000 | 0 |
| 2 | 2021-06-15 | 2021-07-20 | 2000 | 4000 |

Pandas equivalent of what I am looking for would be:

```
def to_value(row):
    return dt[(dt['pay_dt']<row['pay_dt'])&(dt['pay_dt']<row['bill_dt'])&(dt['buyer_id']==row['buyer_id'])].amount.sum()

dt['new_col']=dt.apply(to_value,axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas_udf()` and do conditional processing there:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Window
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

def conditional_sum(data: pd.DataFrame) -> int:
    df = data.apply(pd.Series)  # transform dict into separate columns
    return df.loc[df['Bill date'].max() > df['Payment Date']]['Amount'].sum()

udf_conditional_sum = F.pandas_udf(conditional_sum, IntegerType())

w = Window.partitionBy("Buyer").orderBy("Bill date").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)

(
    df
    .withColumn("Conditional sum", udf_conditional_sum(F.struct("Bill date", "Payment Date", "Amount")).over(w))
    .show(truncate=False)
)
```