# PySpark dataframe cummulative sum based on 2 conditions

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, cumsum

Hi I have a data as below

```
id      state   start_time                      end_time            start_unix_timestamp        date        t_duration_session
id_1    4       7/28/2022 23:32:22.839      7/28/2022 23:39:57.842      1659051142839280        7/28/2022           455
id_1    7       7/28/2022 23:39:57.842      7/28/2022 23:39:58.344      1659051597842430        7/28/2022           0.5
id_1    9       7/28/2022 23:39:58.344      7/28/2022 23:51:40.342      1659051598344810        7/28/2022           702
id_1    4       7/28/2022 23:51:40.342      7/28/2022 23:56:41.841      1659052300342920        7/28/2022           301.5
id_1    2       7/28/2022 23:56:41.841      7/28/2022 23:57:41.841      1659052601841420        7/28/2022           60
id_1    11      7/28/2022 23:57:41.841      8/1/2022 0:41:12.265        1659052661841300        7/28/2022       261810.42
id_1    5       8/1/2022 0:41:12.265        8/1/2022 1:01:59.766        1659314472265650        8/1/2022        1247.5
id_1    4       8/1/2022 1:01:59.766        8/1/2022 1:08:37.761        1659315719766310        8/1/2022        397.99
id_1    9       8/1/2022 1:08:37.761        8/1/2022 1:09:45.261        1659316117761170        8/1/2022        67.5
id_1    4       8/1/2022 1:09:45.261        8/1/2022 1:10:01.262        1659316185261390        8/1/2022        16
id_1    5       8/1/2022 1:10:01.262        8/1/2022 1:10:41.762        1659316201262440        8/1/2022        40.5
id_1    4       8/1/2022 1:10:41.762        8/1/2022 1:16:29.258        1659316241762900        8/1/2022        347.5
id_2    9       8/1/2022 1:16:29.258        8/1/2022 1:18:14.758        1659316589258510        8/1/2022        105.5
id_2    4       8/1/2022 1:18:14.758        8/1/2022 1:20:56.758        1659316694758950        8/1/2022        162
id_2    10      8/1/2022 1:20:56.758        8/1/2022 1:20:57.258        1659316856758970        8/1/2022        0.5
id_2    2       8/1/2022 1:20:57.258        8/1/2022 1:21:55.259        1659316857258970        8/1/2022        58
id_2    11      8/1/2022 1:21:55.259        8/1/2022 4:55:38.537        1659316915259090        8/1/2022        12823.28
id_2    2       8/1/2022 4:55:38.537        8/1/2022 4:55:43.537        1659329738537600        8/1/2022        5
id_2    3       8/1/2022 4:55:43.537        8/1/2022 4:55:45.537        1659329743537620        8/1/2022        2
id_2    4       8/1/2022 4:55:45.537        8/1/2022 5:00:57.360        1659329745537600        8/1/2022        311.82
```

I am trying to calculate cummulative sum of t_duration which resets to zero each time state == 9
and once t_duration goes > 300s from state = 9 cuumulative sum should again reset

expected result as follows

```
id      state   start_time                      end_time            start_unix_timestamp        date        t_duration_session    expected result
id_1    4       7/28/2022 23:32:22.839      7/28/2022 23:39:57.842      1659051142839280        7/28/2022           455                 0
id_1    7       7/28/2022 23:39:57.842      7/28/2022 23:39:58.344      1659051597842430        7/28/2022           0.5                 0
id_1    9       7/28/2022 23:39:58.344      7/28/2022 23:51:40.342      1659051598344810        7/28/2022           702                 0
id_1    4       7/28/2022 23:51:40.342      7/28/2022 23:56:41.841      1659052300342920        7/28/2022           301.5               301.5
id_1    2       7/28/2022 23:56:41.841      7/28/2022 23:57:41.841      1659052601841420        7/28/2022           60                  0
id_1    11      7/28/2022 23:57:41.841      8/1/2022 0:41:12.265        1659052661841300        7/28/2022       261810.42               0
id_1    5       8/1/2022 0:41:12.265        8/1/2022 1:01:59.766        1659314472265650        8/1/2022        1247.5                  0
id_1    4       8/1/2022 1:01:59.766        8/1/2022 1:08:37.761        1659315719766310        8/1/2022        397.99                  0
id_1    9       8/1/2022 1:08:37.761        8/1/2022 1:09:45.261        1659316117761170        8/1/2022        67.5                    0
id_1    4       8/1/2022 1:09:45.261        8/1/2022 1:10:01.262        1659316185261390        8/1/2022        16                      16
id_1    5       8/1/2022 1:10:01.262        8/1/2022 1:10:41.762        1659316201262440        8/1/2022        40.5                    56.5
id_1    4       8/1/2022 1:10:41.762        8/1/2022 1:16:29.258        1659316241762900        8/1/2022        347.5                   404
id_2    9       8/1/2022 1:16:29.258        8/1/2022 1:18:14.758        1659316589258510        8/1/2022        105.5                   0
id_2    4       8/1/2022 1:18:14.758        8/1/2022 1:20:56.758        1659316694758950        8/1/2022        162                     162
id_2    10      8/1/2022 1:20:56.758        8/1/2022 1:20:57.258        1659316856758970        8/1/2022        0.5                     162.5
id_2    2       8/1/2022 1:20:57.258        8/1/2022 1:21:55.259        1659316857258970        8/1/2022        58                      220.5
id_2    11      8/1/2022 1:21:55.259        8/1/2022 4:55:38.537        1659316915259090        8/1/2022        12823.28                13043.78
id_2    2       8/1/2022 4:55:38.537        8/1/2022 4:55:43.537        1659329738537600        8/1/2022        5                           0
id_2    3       8/1/2022 4:55:43.537        8/1/2022 4:55:45.537        1659329743537620        8/1/2022        2                           0
id_2    4       8/1/2022 4:55:45.537        8/1/2022 5:00:57.360        1659329745537600        8/1/2022        311.82                      0
```

I tried following code but not getting desired results

```
w = Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('start_time')
 df_grp = (df.withColumn("time",F.when(F.col('state')==9,0).otherwise(F.col('t_duration_session')))
                  .withColumn("grp",F.sum((F.col("state") == 9).cast("int")).over(w))
                  .withColumn( "t_diff", F.sum(F.col("expected_result")).over(Window.partitionBy("grp").orderBy("start_time"))))
```

could anybody help me with this

Comment: why was 347.5 considered in the cum sum and not 0.5, 702?

Comment: @anonymous13 You can check this if it helps you out https://stackoverflow.com/a/73278159/4648969

Answer (score 0):

why i can see this kind of result .

```
my question : first state=9 having time 2022/07/28 23:59:58 the next row is having time_start 7/28/2022 23:51:40.342 so
how come i am getting expected result 301.5 as the time diff of above two is more than 300 sec 

data example:

id_1    9       7/28/2022 23:39:58.344      7/28/2022 23:51:40.342      1659051598344810        7/28/2022           702                 0
id_1    4       7/28/2022 23:51:40.342      7/28/2022 23:56:41.841      1659052300342920        7/28/2022           301.5               301.5
id_1    2       7/28/2022 23:56:41.841      7/28/2022 23:57:41.841      1659052601841420        7/28/2022           60                  0
id_1    11      7/28/2022 23:57:41.841      8/1/2022 0:41:12.265        1659052661841300        7/28/2022       261810.42               0
id_1    5       8/1/2022 0:41:12.265        8/1/2022 1:01:59.766        1659314472265650        8/1/2022        1247.5                  0 

**but I do have working solution just need confirmation before posting anything**
```

Comment: kindly modify the outcome or clarify my doubts for helping you out

thanks

Comment: time diff is calculated between end_time of current row and end_timestamp of previous row

Comment: kindly edit the question as well so that it will be good for everybody.

Comment: @anonymous13

by your logic Could you please explain how come the current end_timestamp and previous is greater than 300 sec and occurring after state=9 , 
how come  expected result  is 301 instead of 0.

data example :


id_1    9       7/28/2022 23:39:58.344      7/28/2022 23:51:40.342      1659051598344810        7/28/2022           702                 0
id_1    4       7/28/2022 23:51:40.342      7/28/2022 23:56:41.841      1659052300342920        7/28/2022           301.5               301.5